# How do I allow end-user to add data to JSON file

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I'm a novice when it comes to programming so bear with me. Currently I have a recycler view which pulls data from a JSON file in my assets folder and displays it. On the same screen where it is displayed I have created an 'add' button. This takes the user to another screen with a bunch of edit text fields where they can enter their own data, however, it currently does nothing. From my understanding, JSON files are read-only and so in order to add an element to the JSON array it needs to be saved to either internal or external storage (which I have no clue how to do). I have basically just followed this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zdfbHzBmzk8&t=1859s) and now want to add a button where the user can input data and it gets added to the JSON.

*Context:*
The application is supposedly for a car dealership. I need to be able to create a list which displays the current stock of vehicles the dealership has. This is the data in the JSON file. The user should be able to add vehicles to the list, delete vehicles from the list or mark the vehicle as sold which should move it to a different activity and delete it from the current stock list. I will also need to be able to sort the list 3 different ways using a bubble, insertion and selection sort and I have a feeling this would be easier with my data stored in the JSON file.

TL/DR: How can I allow the user to add elements to a JSON file/array?

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform the `add/remove` function on the JSON file which is in the app's `asset` folder. You can simply achieve this functionality in two ways:

1. Either you create a file that is stored locally on the mobile device and every time you need to add or remove some data from that file, you will need to read and then update that file.
2. Or you can create a local `DB` in your app, where you can store, add or update data based on your requirement.

From the above 2 ways, the second one (with `DB`) is more efficient than the first one. Also, you will find many resources that can help you in implementing that functionality.